# Regression problem

Tags: regression, self-study, confidence-interval

Regression was estimated using OLS. We get y=a0 + a1x1 + a2x2 + error. We know covariance matrix ∑ of our estimator.

1. How to get confidence interval for a1/a2 ratio?
2. In what case would the confidence interval be bigger - if there is positive correlation between a1 and a2 or if there is no correlation?

I have some feeling it has to do with Cholesky's decomposition of ∑ . First one is only concerned with description of the procedure. I got it at my exams today and had no idea how to suss it out ;) any ideas?